# Problem with newest com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads version

Tags: android, gradle, ads, gradle-plugin

I use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` library in my project. When I have `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0`, application works, but when I change it to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0`, which is the newest version, I got:

```
Execution failed for task ':MyDrDiabetologia:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':MyDrDiabetologia:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-ads-22.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AsmClassesTransform: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\caches\transforms-3\95231dc48c3ebce7a1af1e21a0ad69f5\transformed\jetified-play-services-ads-22.0.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error occurred while instrumenting class com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaqx

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyDrDiabetologia:mergeExtDexDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at [...]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform play-services-ads-22.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingAsyncArtifactListener$TransformedArtifact.lambda$visit$2(TransformingAsyncArtifactListener.java:232)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingAsyncArtifactListener$TransformedArtifact.visit(TransformingAsyncArtifactListener.java:224)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet$StartVisitAction.visitResults(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$600(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$3.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:249)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$300(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.lambda$visitArtifacts$0(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsUnmanagedWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1497)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:333)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.PropertyFileCollection.visitChildren(PropertyFileCollection.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:375)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputFileProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitRegularInputs(TaskExecution.java:322)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter.fingerprintInputProperties(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateWithOutputs(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionState$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:281)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Execution failed for AsmClassesTransform: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\caches\transforms-3\95231dc48c3ebce7a1af1e21a0ad69f5\transformed\jetified-play-services-ads-22.0.0-runtime.jar.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.lambda$mapResult$3(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.mapFailure(Try.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.mapResult(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.lambda$processDeferredOutput$0(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.access$000(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.lambda$processDeferredOutput$1(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$3.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$1.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation.lambda$flatMap$3(CacheableInvocation.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$3.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingAsyncArtifactListener$TransformedArtifact.finalizeValue(TransformingAsyncArtifactListener.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingAsyncArtifactListener$TransformedArtifact.run(TransformingAsyncArtifactListener.java:136)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$QueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:238)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.doRunBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.lambda$runBatch$0(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractResourceLockRegistry.whileDisallowingLockChanges(AbstractResourceLockRegistry.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.whileDisallowingProjectLockChanges(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.lambda$runBatch$1(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:223)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:191)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while instrumenting class com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaqx
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.instrumentation.AsmInstrumentationManager.doInstrumentClass(AsmInstrumentationManager.kt:290)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.instrumentation.AsmInstrumentationManager.instrumentClassToJar(AsmInstrumentationManager.kt:342)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.instrumentation.AsmInstrumentationManager.instrumentClassesFromJarToJar(AsmInstrumentationManager.kt:157)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AsmClassesTransform.transform(AsmClassesTransform.kt:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformer.transform(DefaultTransformer.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$AbstractTransformerExecution$1.call(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:290)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$AbstractTransformerExecution$1.call(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:285)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at 
[...]
org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.DefaultImmutableWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$3(DefaultImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:191)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:188)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.DefaultImmutableWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(DefaultImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.lambda$executeDeferred$0(IdentityCacheStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.cache.Cache.lambda$get$0(Cache.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.ManualEvictionInMemoryCache.get(ManualEvictionInMemoryCache.java:30)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory$CrossBuildCacheRetainingDataFromPreviousBuild.get(DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory.java:255)
    at org.gradle.cache.Cache.get(Cache.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.lambda$executeDeferred$1(IdentityCacheStep.java:47)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.myBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.myMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs 'pl', 'en', 'de'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            initWith debug
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
    }

    configurations {
        debugImplementation
        releaseImplementation
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            enableV3Signing true
            enableV4Signing true
        }
    }
    lint {
        checkDependencies true
    }
    namespace 'com.lekseek.libadmob'
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api project(':LibNavUtils')
 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
    constraints {
        implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0') {
            because 'bez tego adsy nie dzialaja na android 12'
        }
    }
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
}
```

Removing contraints not working too, and it's needed, because without it ads not working on Android 12.

I want use the newest `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` library, what should I repair?

Comment: any answers ? i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

I updated `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` to the newest version (21.3.0) and the problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

*Multidex Builder is the source of the issue. In reality, this frequently occurs when you import many packages into your file, which cannot all fit into a single.dex build, necessitating the use of multidex.*

**Open android/app/build.gradle and add the following lines of code:**

**Note: Make sure you use latest multidex version**

```
 dependencies {   
      implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' 
  } 

 android {
     defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
     } 
}
```

Comment: It don't change anything, the same error.

Comment: Do you add the above in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes. I used multidex with other app, so I know how to use it. But it not helps in this problem.

Comment: Then make sure, your gradle version and API level will be compatible with the latest gms play service dependency.

Comment: It is compatible.